# Luis intent handler is throwing exception into bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to find out an activity text into a LUIS dialog. I am using the LUIS intent handler:

```
[LuisIntent("")]
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{       
    await context.PostAsync("I have no idea what you are talking about.");
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

but this throws an Exception:

> File of type 'text/plain'

Can anyone suggest me why this happens? I also put a breakpoint but it isn't hit.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce, are you able to post more of your code or put your project in a repo?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing that problem because of the intent handler signature. Notice the `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result`. Re-writing like this will work:

```
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I have no idea what you are talking about.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```

Instead of an `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>`, you should use `LuisResult`. Alternatively, `LuisDialog` does target an intent handler overload with three parameters and this will work too:

```
    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("I have no idea what you are talking about.");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }
```